# Phonegap input value return [object HTMLInputElement] or empty

Tags: javascript, cordova, get, element

Struggling to get the value from an input tag in my phonegap project.

```
<input type="text" class="search-query form-control" value="testvalue" id="isbnnumber"/>
```

This results: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn[object HTMLInputElement]

```
var isbn = document.getElementById("isbnnumber");
```

This results: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn

```
var isbn = document.getElementById("isbnnumber").value;
```

This is the full line that prints those results.

```
var fullurl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn' + isbn;
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://jsbin.com/muvokad/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: var isbn = document.getElementById("isbnnumber").value; works. The fullUrl should be like this one: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=055380457X+isbn

Comment: @Thomas Did  you get the answer or still sucked ??